# Drop down menu disappears too quicky

Tags: css, css-selectors

When I give `top: 2rem` to dropdown-content it works fine but doesn't look good.

It does look fine at 3rem but dropdown just disappears when I hover it. I tried with :focus and :active still same.

[image: Current result]

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

.consumer-header__menu-label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3rem;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 260px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.eds-dropdown-menu__contents:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="consumer-header__menu">
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="eds-dropdown-menu__contents">
      <div class="consumer-header__menu-label">
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <li>Why Eventbrite?</li>
          <li>Pricing</li>
          <li>Resources</li>
        </div>
        Organize
        <span class="eds-dropdown-menu__icon">
           Custom Icons Component
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have probably a small gap between your "button" and the dropdown and as soon as your mouse reaches the gap the hover style does no longer apply. You can ensure to not have a gap by placing your dropdown exactly at the lower edge of your "button" with `top: 100%;` instead of `top: 3rem;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the native HTML [`<details>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) for this:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

details {
  min-width: 260px;
}

details:hover, summary:focus {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #eee;
}

details ul {
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="consumer-header__menu">
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="eds-dropdown-menu__contents">
      <details>
        <summary>Organize</summary>
        <ul>
          <li>Why Eventbrite?</li>
          <li>Pricing</li>
          <li>Resources</li>
        </ul>
      </details>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```